Proving a Brownian Motion is a Gaussian Process
I was reading these two questions here:

How to prove Brownian motion is Gaussian Process?
What is the difference between a Gaussian process and Brownian motion?

I am trying to understand the following point: A Brownian Motion is defined in terms of Normal Distributions (i.e. via the Wiener Process) - therefore, is not a Gaussian Process simply by definition?
Therefore in this question here:How to prove Brownian motion is Gaussian Process? , why is such a long proof required to prove that a Brownian Motion is a Gaussian Process?
Thansk!

A Gaussian process is, by definition, a process whose finite dimensional marginal distributions are (jointly) normal.
Now take a Brownian motion (on $[0,1]$). Usually it is defined as follows:

$W_0 = 0$
$P(\omega\in\Omega : \text{$t\mapsto W_t(\omega)$ is continuous}) = 1$
For all finite $S\subset[0,1]$ it holds that the vector $(W_{s_i} - W_{s_{i-1}})_{i=1}^n$ has a centered normal distribution with variance-covariance matrix $\operatorname{Diag}(s_1 - s_0, s_2 - s_1, ..., s_{n-1} - s_{n-2})$, where $S = \{s_0, s_1, \dots, s_{n-1}\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$.

It takes some work to show that all finite marginals, i.e., the vector $(W_{s_i})_{i=1}^n$ has a multivarite normal distribution for all finite $S\subset[0,1]$ with $S = \{s_0,s_1,...,s_{n-1}\}$.
However, you can also define the Brownian motion in many different ways, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion
One way would be to define a Brownian motion by saying it's a Gaussian process with a particular variance-covariance function. This is explained in the first question.
Eventually it depends what you prefer or what the references you are working with prefer.

A brief proof that BM is Gaussian is available once you know that the sum of independent normal random variables is again normal. Using Syd Amerikaner's. notation, one wants to show that if $(W_s)_{s\in[0,1]}$ is a standard Brownian motion, then for $0=s_0<s_1<\cdots<s_n\le 1$ the $n$-tuple $(W_{s_1}, W_{s_2},\ldots,W_{s_n})$ has a joint normal distribution. This is true if and only if $\sum_{k=1}^n b_kW_{s_k}$ is a univariate normal random variable, for each choice of $b_1,\ldots,b_n$. But this follows immediately from
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n b_kW_{s_k}=\sum_{j=1}^n c_j(W_{s_j}-W_{s_j-1})
$$
(where $c_j:=\sum_{k=j}^n b_k$), because Brownian motion has independent normal increments.
